# how do I do a command line only boot of CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, boot, dual-boot, live-usb, bootable

**Can someone please explain how to trigger a command line only boot of CentOS 7 from a USB boot stick?**  I want to boot the terminal only and then use the normal CentOS 7 terminal to swap out the graphics card drivers using yum.  That way I will be able to subsequently use the same boot stick to boot the full version of CentOS 7 incuding the gnome gui.

Currently, when I try to boot using the usb stick, the gnome gui cannot be loaded because an attempt to use the graphics card throws a driver error that I want to address by replacing the drivers as above.

Here are the steps that I have taken so far, which are failing:

```
1.) Insert USB boot stick
2.) Turn on power for pc
3.) Press esc every second until a list of options appears
4.) Press F9: Boot Device Options
5.) Three options appear: 
    a.) OS Boot Manager (UEFI) Windows Boot Manager
    b.) USB Hard Drive (UEFI) PNY USB 2.0 FD 
    c.) Boot From EFI File
6.) I selected USB Hard Drive (UEFI) PNY USB 2.0 FD
7.) The computer tried to boot CentOS 7 but crashed and gives the 
    Dracut Emergency Shell instead of the normal terminal.  The Dracut  
    shell does not have all the same commands as the normal terminal.
```

Pressing esc, F2, F12, or del repeatedly did not stop this on a repeated tries either.

What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain how to trigger a command line only boot of CentOS 7 from a USB boot stick?

How about single user mode? Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> at the *CentOS 7* boot menu. Append `init=/sysroot/bin/sh` to the kernel arguments.

```
vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 rd.live.check quiet init=/sysroot/bin/sh
```

And then...

```
chroot /sysroot
```

Comment: I deleted my comments and I created a separate question about this on superuser.com.  I marked your answer as +1.  If you delete your comments and keep your answer, future readers will only see the linux piece of this thread.  Also, if you are willing, I would appreciate your advice on the superuser version of this question at this link: http://superuser.com/questions/930105/installing-64-bit-centos-using-virtualbox

Comment: I want to edit the `/etc/profile` file and I get a permission error. how would I get authenticated

Answer (score 1):

Try booting to single user mode:[click](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/single-user-mode-in-centos-7-rhel-7.html).

After that you could use the command: `init 3` to boot to runlevel 3. I haven't tried this on centos 7. but this is how i did it in previous versions.